# Clustering of 3D data (normals) via DBSCAN

Tags: python, 3d, computer-vision, cluster-analysis

I try to cluster my 3D data (normals) via DBSCAN in order to further segment them with respect to nearest surfaces. In most implementations, there is a 2D data as input-output. It's my first attempt on this so any advice would be helpful.

My current code is based on `sklearn.cluster` package.

How can i do it for 3D data?

My data is located in a numpy array `Z` , with shape `(3, 131072)`
where `3` and `131072` denote `width*height` and `RGB channel` respectively.

My RGB image with normals is:
[image]

Comment: What would be a density based cluster here? I would imagine the vectors are one big blob, since the figure is smooth and not edgy.

Comment: Have you tried plotting the normal vectors?